# Can't modify nginx index.html file

Tags: nginx

If i connect `www.my-hsot.com` then always Output 'Hello!' Text..

But my index.html file content is nothing. I want just blank page..
How can i modified default index file?

Here is my default config :

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /home/me;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.my-hsot.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$request_uri;
    }

   location /.well-known {
        root /home/me/well-known;
   }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        include                  fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_index            index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

And this is nginx default index file(path : /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html)is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set

```
root /home/me;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
...
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$request_uri;
}
```

So, when accessing / nginx will first look for index.php which is passed to the fcgi handler. I guess that's where the "Hello!" comes from: your index.php.

If there is no index.php, it will look for index.html, but in the document root /home/me.

To get a blank page on / you could use something like

```
location ~ "^[/]?$" {
  return 200;
}
```